# AWS Glue Apache Spark appending instead of updating existing data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I'm hoping someone can provide some guidance, so I'm still pretty new to Apache Spark scripting and was hoping someone might be able to shed some light. I'm getting this recurring issue where I'm trying to update an existing records in a catalog table (parquet format) but it just appends the data rather than updating.. any help would be appreciated

I've tried this code snippy where i use a glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog()

```
# Perform the join and update operation
joined_df = address_df.join(
    results_df,
    address_df["cross_reference"] == results_df["cross_reference"],
    "inner"
).withColumn("candidates", F.lit("y")).drop(results_df["cross_reference"])

# Convert the updated DataFrame back to a DynamicFrame
updated_address_dynamic_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(joined_df, glueContext, "updated_address_dynamic_frame")

# Write the updated DynamicFrame back to the data catalog, updating the existing data
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=updated_address_dynamic_frame,
    database="buildings",
    table_name="cur_address",
    additional_options={
        "enableUpdateCatalog": True,
        "updateBehavior": "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE"
    }
)

job.commit()
```

Expected Results:

| address | candidates |
| --- | --- |
| example one | y |
| example two | y |

Actual results:

| address | candidates |
| --- | --- |
| example one | y |
| example one | N/A |
| example two | y |
| example two | N/A |